# How to know where the arrow ends in matplotlib quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have programmed plt.quiver(x,y,u,v,color), where there are arrows that start at x,y and the direction is determined by u,v. My question is how can I know exactly where the arrow ends?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the arrows are of length `length` as described in the [Quiver documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) and are auto-calculated by the matplotlib. I don't know which kwarg may help to return the length.

Another approach could be to define the exact position by scaling the plot with the help of `scale=1, units='xy'`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# define arrow
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
y = np.linspace(1,0,11)
u = v = np.zeros((11,11))
u[5,5] = 0.3
v[5,5] = 0.3
 
plt.quiver(x, y, u, v, scale=1, units='xy')

plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Color arrows that end at a specific point

Applying the principles above could result in:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

n = 11
cx = 0.7 #x-position of specific end point
cy = 0.5 #y-position of specific end point

# define random arrows
x = np.linspace(0,1,n)
y = np.linspace(0,1,n)
u = np.zeros((n,n))
v = np.zeros((n,n))

# color everything black
colors = [(0, 0, 0)]*n*n

# make sure at least some points end at the same point
u[5][5] = 0.2
u[5][8] = -0.1
v[2][7] = 0.3

# search for specific point
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        endPosX = x[i] + u[j][i]
        endPosY = y[j] + v[j][i]

        if np.isclose(endPosX, cx) and np.isclose(endPosY, cy):
            #found specific point -> color it red
            colors[j*n+i] = (1,0,0) 

# plot data
plt.quiver(x, y, u, v, color=colors, scale=1, units='xy')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it is still not very clear for me, so the M here is used to calculate the hypotenuse for the right-angled triangle is it the length or the destination?

Comment: The code is just on example. The hint is `pivot='tip'`. If you use it, the arrows end at (x, y), instead of starting there, which may make more sense when you aim at calculating the end position.

Comment: Thank you but I still did not get it. So I have a list of x,y (start of the arrows). u,v the directions of the arrows. By using pivot='tip', gave me other arrows since now the end position is x,y . I want to calculate the end arrow's position?

Comment: Does the update help? If not, please provide some more information about your data and quiver plot.

Comment: I have this code plt.quiver(x,y,u,v,colour) x,y,u,and v all lists of 1681 items. So, I have now the arrows and they are all black. However, I want to know if the direction(the endpoint) of the arrow is pointing to a specific point let us call it (c,d). Then colour that arrow red. Otherwise, keep it black.

Comment: To do so, I am thinking of comparing the value of x to c and x+u to c so if the x+u is closer to c it means the arrow is getting closer to c,d. and will do it of course to y. Compare y to d and y+v to d.

Comment: Does the update help you?